# Is an un-updated windows instance without internet access safer than an updated one with one way Internet?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, routing, nat

I have several instances running windows server 2012 on AWS. The servers simply share drives for network access, and thus have no Public IP, and are not in a subnet that uses a NAT, aka no internet Access. This has been the case for about 2 years.

There has recently been some concern over the fact that these servers have not downloaded and installed windows updates in over 2 years, and there could be vulnerabilities these servers do not have patched.

The good news is, even if they are compromised somehow they cannot send data outside our network.

Is it worth (from a security pov) adding a NAT to the subnet just to allow these servers to get Updates?

Comment: I think this question is primarily opinion-based, but, you need to patch your servers. You said the servers share network drives, so it's only a matter of time until an infected client connects to them. What's the saying? That an airgap is the gap in a sysadmin's knowledge leading to a false sense of security that the servers are isolated? Besides, patches contain not only security fixes, but also stability, reliability and performance improvements too. Joe's offline WSUS idea is good.

Answer (score 4):

If someone compromises other servers they can end up being a proxy / bastion to let people attack those file servers. IMHO yes it's worth applying Windows updates. To keep costs down you could run the NAT instance a couple of hours per week, around the time windows updates are scheduled.

Answer (score 4):

It might be worthwhile looking into WSUS Offline Update. You can download updates on a separate machine/instance and transfer them internally to the servers in question. That way you won't need to make changes to your existing configuration.

http://download.wsusoffline.net